# is windows flavor path not working for pathlib under linux python?

Tags: python, linux, pathlib

In windows, with pathlib.Path, both windows flavor path and linux flavor path work fine, but in linux it seems only linux flavor path works, is this expected?

In windows:

- both Path("/windows/Logs") and Path(r"\windows\Logs") could return windowspath, and work fine

```sh
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("\\windows\\Logs")
WindowsPath('/windows/Logs')
>>> Path("/windows/Logs")
WindowsPath('/windows/Logs')
>>> Path("\\windows\\Logs").exists()
True
>>> Path("/windows/Logs").exists()
True
>>> (Path("\\windows\\Logs")/"../Logs").resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Windows/Logs')
```

In Linux:

- Though both Path("/usr/src") and Path(r"\usr\src") return posixpath, but Path(r"\usr\src") seems not work

```sh
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 14:58:38)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/usr/src/app")
PosixPath('/usr/src/app')
>>> Path(r"\usr\src\app")
PosixPath('\\usr\\src\\app')
>>> Path("/usr/src/app").exists()
True
>>> Path(r"\usr\src\app").exists()
False
>>> (Path("/usr/src") / r"..\src\app").resolve()
PosixPath('/usr/src/..\\src\\app')
>>> (Path("/usr/src") / r"..\src\app").exists()
False
>>> (Path("/usr/src") / r"..\src\app").as_posix()
'/usr/src/..\\src\\app'
```

Comment: seems only `PureWindowsPath("\\usr\\src").as_posix()` does the conversion works